# Apigee Admin - cannot create appropriate user permissions

Tags: ios, ant, apigee

I am using the Apigee BaaS admin web portal and Apigee iOS SDK, trying to create the appropriate Apache Ant pattern to permit me to create a relationship between a user entity and a device entity.

By default, whenever you create a user using Facebook sign in, there is already a relationship connecting between these 2 collections (/users and /devices). But whenever I cURL GET request this, I return no entities. Therefore I tried to POST create the relationship manually.

An example of the relationship I try to create using the iOS Apigee SDK:

```
ApigeeClientResponse *registerResponse = [[self.apigeeClient dataClient] connectEntities:@"users" connectorID:user_uuid type:@"devices" connecteeID:userDeviceUUID];

@try {

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", registerResponse.response);

} @catch (NSException *e) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", e);

}
```

The response I get:

```
Response: Subject does not have permission [applications:post:xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx:/users/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/devices/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx]
```

I have tried the following patterns which so far have not worked for me:

```
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:**/devices"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/devices/**"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:**/devices"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:**/devices/**"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/users/*/devices/**"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/users/*/devices/*"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/users/${user}/devices/**"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/users/${user}/devices/*"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/users/${user}/devices"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/users/${user}/**"}
POST /roles/default/permissions {"permission":"get,post,put:/users/${user}/*"}
```

I have narrowed it down to these possible reasons why this may not be working:

- A problem with my Apache Ant patterns
- These collections are default Apigee collections and may have strict rules tied to them.
- A problem with the Apache iOS SDK

Can anyone suggest a pattern, or help me identify why I don't have permissions to make this relationship?

Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Chris, after you set the permission, are you passing a token with your calls?  Meaning, did you log your user in prior to trying to create the connection?

If so, then the Default role is the one you want to use.  If not, then the Guest role is the one that would be invoked.  Alternatively, you can create a new role and then assign it to the user, or you can set the permissions on the user entity (see the users section admin portal for doing this).

As far as what permission to use, this one should do the trick:

/devices/**

although several of your others should also work:

/users/*/devices/**
/users/${user}/devices/**

I am not aware of any currently pending bug tickets around this issue.  That doesn't mean it isn't a bug.

To test that you are using the correct role, you can add /** for POST, which should allow POST operations to any and all endpoints.

Comment: Hey rockerston, Yes the user is logged in using Facebook at this point and we are also passing the token with each call. Currently all users are put into a group which is assigned the default role which all have these patterns tied to them. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Sort of. All users are going to be get the Default role regardless of whether you assign that role to a group.  You would need to clear out the Default role and make a new one for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks rockerston, I will try this out and get back to you

Comment: Hey Rockerston, thank you for your suggestion but I have created a new role, assigned it to my group, but unfortunately this still does not work; I am still not granted any POST access to these 2 collections. I have double checked and I can confirm that the user is logged in at this point and the token is being sent in each request. Have you any ideas?